# How to place icon at the end in linear progress bar MUI?

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm using MUI v5 to build linear progress bar.I have a scenario where if value in progress bar is 100%,I need to show tick icon at the end.The width of the bar with/without tick icon should be same,meaning icon shouldn't be placed after the bar.It should be at the end of bar.I tried with stylings and able to place tick icon at the end.But I'm unable to show the icon clearly as the bar overlaps with tick icon.

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", position: "relative", alignItems: "center" }}>
                            <LinearProgress
                              variant="determinate"
                              sx={{
                                width: "100%",
                                borderRadius: "4px"
                              }}
                              
                              value={50}
                            />
                              <CheckCircleIcon sx={{ color: "blue" }} style={{ position: "absolute", width: "20px", display: "flex", justifyContent: "flex-end", right: "-2px", color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }} />
                            
                          </div>
```

Current Design  [image: Current code]
Expected Design  [image: Expected design]

Comment: Try giving z-index to the tick icon

Comment: @AYK Tried that already.Didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a live demo where I've customized an MUI [`Slider`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/) with a checkmark `SliderThumb`.

[image: Edit CustomizedSlider Material Demo (forked)]

[image]

The demo includes the foundation for using this as a progress bar:

1. Disable the slider to ignore user input. Keep in mind that disabling will change the color to gray. You can override disabled behavior through [`.Mui-disabled`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/slider/#css)
2. Set the slider's `value` using a state variable that corresponds to your current progress

You may also choose to customize a `LinearProgress` component in the same way I've customized the `Slider` above. See the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-progress/#customization) for `LinearProgress` customization.

Full slider code:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Slider, { SliderThumb } from '@mui/material/Slider'
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import CheckCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle'

const CheckMarkSlider = styled(Slider)(({ theme }) =>
({
  color: '#3a8589',
  height: 3,
  padding: '13px 0',
  '& .MuiSlider-thumb':
  {
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    border: '1px solid currentColor',
    '&:hover': {
      boxShadow: '0 0 0 8px rgba(58, 133, 137, 0.16)',
    },
    '& .checkmark-bar':
    {
      height: 9,
      width: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'currentColor',
      marginLeft: 1,
      marginRight: 1,
    },
  },
  '& .MuiSlider-track':
  {
    height: 3,
  },
  '& .MuiSlider-rail':
  {
    color: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#bfbfbf' : '#d8d8d8',
    opacity: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? undefined : 1,
    height: 3,
  },
}))

const CheckMarkThumbComponent = (props) =>
{
  const { children, ...other } = props

  return (
    <SliderThumb {...other}>
      {children}
      <CheckCircleIcon />
    </SliderThumb>
  )
}

const CustomizedSlider = () =>
{
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(20)

  React.useEffect(() =>
  {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => setValue(Math.random() * 100), 500)
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
  }, [value])

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 320 }}>
      <CheckMarkSlider
        value = {value}
        disabled
        components={{ Thumb: CheckMarkThumbComponent }} />
    </Box>
  )
}

export default CustomizedSlider
```